# Как упростить код ввода данных с клавиатуры в Groovy

Tags: ввод, groovy

Перевод из латинской системы счисления в арабскую:

```
def Vvod () {
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))
  print "Vvedite Rim = "; Rim = br.readLine()
}

def rimArab (Rim) {
  Map rimArab = [ "I":1, "V":5, "X":10, "L":50, "C":100, "D":500, "M":1000]
  f = Rim.replace("IV", "IIII").replace("IX", "VIIII").replace("XL", "XXXX").replace("XC", "LXXXX").replace("CD", "CCCC").replace("CM", "DCCCC")
  Arab = 0; for(i in f) { Arab = Arab + rimArab[i]}
}

def Vivod () { print "Arab = "; println Arab}

while (1) {
  Vvod (); 
  if(Rim == "n") {break}
  rimArab (Rim) 
  Vivod ()
}
```

Вопрос: как упростить функцию `Vvod()`?

Answer (score 0):

Есть несколько способов прочитать из консоли в `Groovy`.

- `def line = System.console().readLine "введите строку ="` - данный способ не всегда работает, т.к. объект `console` может быть не доступен. (У меня в **Intellij Idea**, возник **NPE**)
- Воспользоваться методом `newReader` : `def param = System.in.newReader().readLine()`